# data-nav-section from second html back to index.html not working correcty

Tags: sections

Good day, I'm stuck here.
In my index.html there are header options to navigate directly to the following sections:

```
                <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="werkwijze">Werkwijze</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="tarieven">Tarieven</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="faq">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="contact">Contact</a></li>
```

This al works well. So far so good.

Now I have a portfolio html page with the same sections in the header that should navigate back to the index page.

```
                <li><a href="index.html" class="transition" data-nav-section="home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html" class="transition" data-nav-section="portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html" class="transition" data-nav-section="werkwijze">Werkwijze</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html" class="transition" data-nav-section="tarieven">Tarieven</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html" class="transition" data-nav-section="faq">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html" class="transition" data-nav-section="contact">Contact</a></li>
```

When I click on any option in the header (of the portfolio html) it does navigate to the index page but not to the correct section but always to the top of the page (home).
So what I want is that I click "Contact" in the header of the portfolio html and that I get to the contact section in the index page.

Does anyone have advice for me how to get it done?

Comment: Anyone have an answer?